# Matlab Cross correlation vs Correlation Coefficient question

Tags: matlab, analysis, correlation, data-analysis

I'm writing a program in C++ but using data from matlab involving Cross Correlation.
I understand that when I do a correlation on 2 sets of data it gives me a single correlation coefficient number indicating if they are related. But I'm wanting to use Cross Correlation on the **data series**. When I run Cross Correlation on Matlab it gives me a lot of data and when plotted the plot looks like a triangle... I understand Correlation is supposed to be somewhere between +/- 1 but the data toward the tip of the triangle doesn't go up at the same time etc. Do I have a confusion with what Cross Correlation is giving me or is the data that Cross Correlation gives me actually correlation coefficients for each point s(t),p(t) for instance? Any help with clarifying is appreciated.

**Edit 1 (after Phonon's Response)**

My main question is: Is the data that I get when I cross correlate 2 data series the correlation coefficient for each point. For instance, (0,10) and (0,8); Is the data I'm getting the correlation coefficient of those 2 plots at x=0 ?

Comment: How are you computing the correlation?

Comment: xcorr but my main question is Is the data that I get when I cross correlate 2 data series the correlation coefficient for each point. For instance, (0,10) and (0,8); Is the data I'm getting the correlation coefficient of those 2 plots at x=0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab `xcorr(x,x)` gives auto-correlation of signal x. It is *not* scaled, it's simply a vector of inner products of the signal with shifted versions of itself. In order to scale it, use `xcorr(x,x,'coeff')`. This command will scale your auto-correlation by signal's energy (in other words it will divide each coefficient by value of coefficient at zero lag). Note that when you're doing *cross-correlation*, `xcorr(x,y'coeff')`, you will *not* get a value of 1 and zero lag, because the scaling is performed differently. It will only be 1 if you're correlating a signal with itself (I wish SO supported math formulas so that I could write it out for you).

Comment: That makes sense but I need the cross correlation on 2 data sets not autocorrelation which is crosscorrelation on one data set and itself or whatever

Comment: Use `'coeff'`, it will scale the data. All I was trying to say is that you will only get exactly 1 at zero lag if you correlate a signal with itself.

Comment: Phonon Do you understand my revised question above and does your answer still apply?

Comment: I don't think I understand it well. It's practically indecipherable.

Comment: Correlation coefficients do are not calculated for each point. They're calculated for each unit shift.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/corrcoef.html), not `xcorr`.

Comment: @Tyler31: It is not clear what you mean.  In general, a correlation coefficient is a single value for two sets of data, describing whether there's an underlying linear relationship between them.  It's not clear what "doing a corrcoeff for each point" would mean.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear about several concepts.

1. [Cross-correlation vs. cross-covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Cross-correlation_of_stochastic_processes). The main difference is that cross-covariance normalize the data by subtracting the mean.
2. cross-covariance vs. normalized cross-covariance. The later one is divided by the standard deviation of the the input.
3. normalized cross-covariance and correlation coefficient. The later one is the special case of the former one at delay=0.